# Visual Basic Focus()

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a unit converter written in Visual Basic using Visual Studio 2012. It uses two text boxes and two combo boxes. It is programmed to send the focus back to the first text box after making a selection in either combo boxes, but after triggering a textChanged event in the second text box, and then making another selection in either of the combo boxes, the Focus() seems to be selecting all the text data in the first text box. I want only the blinking cursor to be in the box. When all the text is selected like that, it deletes the box when you try to type another digit in there because all of the text is selected. Please give me a solution or a suggestion. If you need some code to look at, just let me know and I will put together a somewhat small block of it to get my point across. Thanks in advance!

By the way, I am using Focus() to send the focus where I need it to go in this program.

Comment: events are there for you to RESPOND to user actions.  it is generally not a good idea to be triggering them as you can get into a race situation or confuse the user.  but you should be able to set the `SelectedText` to String.Empty or "" in the Focus event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want the cursor to be at the end of the TextBox?

```
    TextBox1.Focus()
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength
```